# Problema con tooltip creado con css y datatable de jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

Estoy creando tooltip para que al ponerse encima del texto de cada celda de un datatable se muestre un tooltip con ese texto pero la versión larga, y el datatable no me está dejando. Me muestra el tooltip pero me lo muestra dentro de la celda y no hay manera de que se vea el tootltip por encima del datatable. Lo he probado aumentado el z-index del tooltip pero nada. ¿Alguna solución?

Adjunto el código:

**CSS**

```
/* Clase que tendrá el tooltip */
    .claseTooltip {
        position: relative;     /* Esta clase tiene que ser posición relativa */
        color: #FF8C00;         /* Color de texto */
}

/* El tooltip */
.claseTooltip span {
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.9);
    border: 2px solid #87CEFA;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #333;
    color: #87CEFA;
    display: none;/* El tooltip por defecto estará oculto */
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 35px;
    max-width: 6000px;
    position: relative;  /* El tooltip se posiciona de forma absoluta para no modificar el aspecto del resto de la página */
    top: 15px;  /* Posición a partir de la parte superior del primer elemento madre con posición relativa */
    left: 100px; /* Posición a partir de la parte izquierda del primer elemento padre con posición relativa */
    z-index: 100000000000; /* Poner un z-index alto para que aparezca por encima del resto de elementos */
}

/* El tooltip cuando se muestra */
.claseTooltip:hover span {
    display: block; /* Para mostrarlo simplemente usamos display block, por ejemeplo */
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT (EN LA CONFIGURACIÓN DEL DATATABLE)**

```
columns: [
    {data: 
        function (data, type, row, meta) {
            if(data.observacion== null){
                return '';
            }else{
                return '<div class="claseTooltip">'+data.observacion+'<span>'+data.observacion+'</span></div>';
            }
        }
    },
],
```

Y así es como se ve con lo citado anteriormente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen tengo el cursor encima del texto de la segunda celda, y el tooltip aparece pero dentro de la celda. ¿Habría forma de que se viera pero fuera del datatable/celda?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el HTML del tooltip renderizado? He hecho una prueba rápida y se muestra bien el tooltip https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/xpvt214o/158067/

Comment: Claro, es que los elementos html no se crean en la parte html, se crean de forma dinámica con la configuracion del datatable. Las filas y columnas y todo eso se crea de forma dinámica.

Comment: Por eso te decía si puedes mostrarnos el html renderizado :)

Comment: Que significa mostrarlo renderizado? Discúlpeme pero soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Simplemente que muestres cómo queda el HTML después de cargar las filas y columnas dinámicamente.

Comment: Podrías envolver la tabla en un container con `position:absolute` y darle position absolute al tooltip?

Comment: ¿Has probado con `position: absolute` como te han comentado? ¿Podrías darnos un enlace a tus pruebas o intentar poner un código funcional con el que trabajar? Pásate por [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Tambien puedes agregar el position y el z-index en tu css para mostrar el tooltip en frente de todos los elementos de la tabla

```
.claseTooltip:hover span {
     display: block;
     z-index:9;
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
}
```